# Distribution of X SQRT(XX+YY) where X and Y are Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a complex variable $Z = X + i Y$ where $X$ and $Y$ are Gaussian iid with zero mean and $\sigma^2$ variance.

I am interested in ${\mathbb E} ( X |Z|^p )$.
Is there a known distribution for this?

I know that $|Z|$ is Rayleigh distributed. However, for my expression I would have ${\mathbb E} (X+iY)|Z|^p = {\mathbb E} X|Z|^p + i {\mathbb E} Y|Z|^p = (1+i) {\mathbb E} X|Z|^p$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write $Z=R\exp i\Theta$, where in requiring $\Theta\in [0,\,2\pi]$ we impose a uniform distribution on $\Theta$. You're studying $R^{p+1}\cos\Theta$,  a product of two independent variables. In particular, the mean is $0$ because the cosine averages to $0$.

Comment: That's a great input! Actually I want ${\mathbb E}(|Z|^p Z)$ anway (also ${\mathbb E}((|Z|^p Z)^2)$). So with $Z=|Z|e^{i \operatorname{arg}Z}$ I am writing
${\mathbb E}(R e^{i\phi})$ = ${\mathbb E}(R) {\mathbb E}(e^{i\phi})$ with $R$ Rayleigh and $\phi$ uniformly distributed (and independent).
Now I am trying to obtain ${\mathbb E}((e^{i\phi})^q) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i q \phi} d\phi = \operatorname{sinc}(q)$ which is always zero.
What am I missing?

Comment: @divB Look beyond integer-valued $q$ if you want something non-trivial.

Comment: I know sinc is nonzero for non-integers but $q$ just happens to be 1 or 2 ... and zero doesn't make sense nor does it match with the numerics in MATLAB. I assume the assumption of independence is not true or so?

Comment: Hmm I think I found the trouble somewhere else ... `x=sigma*(randn(N,1)+i*randn(N,1)); mean(abs(x)^p .* x)` gives me zero on average.